# display pre-selected form values not 'stick' on on-change event in Polymer JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, polymer, dom-repeat

This is in Polymer JS. `onchange` is actually `on-change`.

I have a dropdown, with two items to select. Each item (commercial = 2, residential = 1) has specific fields in the DOM-repeat portion of the application, some would come with default values preselected on page load. For example, when Commercial is selected, the value for `# of sites` should be preselected to 1.

When I change the first business type (commercial) to the next, the fields get displayed in the dom-repeat should show the preselected values, instead, the fields don't display those preselected values that we saw on the first-page load (by default page load with `Commercial` business type being selected in the dropdown). my code is below:

//HTML dropdowns for business type (singleselect) and service type (multiselect)

```
<div class="flex-item" labelsTooltip">
  <se-singleselect title="Contract Business Type"
                   selected="{{_contract.businessTypeId}}" 
                   fieldvalue="businessTypeId"
                   fieldname="name" 
                   desc="Contract Business Type*"
                   datasrc="{{businessTypeItems}}" 
                   id="businessTypeSelect"
                   on-change="_refreshFields"
  ></se-singleselect>
</div>

<div class="flex-item labelsTooltip">
  <se-multiselect title="Service Type"
                  selected="{{_contract.serviceTypeIds}}" 
                  fieldvalue="serviceTypeId"
                  fieldname="name"
                  desc="Service Type*"
                  datasrc="{{serviceTypeItems}}"
                  id="serviceTypeSelect"
   ></se-multiselect>
</div>
```

//HTML dom-repeat by service types, three fields that should be auto populated based on business type are included.

```
<template is="dom-repeat"
   items="{{_selectedServiceType(_contract.serviceTypeIds, serviceTypeItems, _contract.businessTypeId)}}"
   as="_serviceTypeDetails">

  <div class="labelsTooltip" id="pricingMethod" style="margin-right: 10px;">
    <se-singleselect title="Pricing Method"
                     selected="{{_serviceTypeDetails.pricingMethodId}}"
                     fieldvalue="pricingMethodId" 
                     fieldname="name"
                     desc="Pricing Method*"
                     datasrc="{{pricingMethodItems}}"
                     id="pricingMethodSelect"
    ></se-singleselect>
  </div>
  
  <div class="flex-item labelsTooltip" style="display:flex; margin: 10px 0 0 15px;">
    <div style="padding-right: 5px;">
      <label title="# of Sites" for="serviceTypeDetails.noOfSites" style="display:block;"># of Sites</label>
      <input type="text"
             value="{{_serviceTypeDetails.noOfSites::input}}"
             on-input="_allowNumbersCharsOnly" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkmark-item chckboxes">
      <input type="checkbox"
             id="chk-start{{index}}"
             checked="{{_serviceTypeDetails.sitesStartDateAligned::change}}">
      <label title="Start Dates are Aligned" for$="chk-start{{index}}" style="font-size: small; line-height: 12px;">Start Dates are Aligned</label>
  </div>
</template>
```

//Script

```
_selectedServiceType(val1, val2, val3) {
  var returnItems = [];
  if (val1 != undefined) {

    if (val1 == '-1') {
      for (var i = 0; i < val2.length; i++) {
        returnItems.push(val2[i]);
      }

    } else {
      var splitVal1 = val1.toString().split(',');

      for (var i = 0; i < val2.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < splitVal1.length; j++) {
          if (splitVal1[j] == val2[i].serviceTypeId) {
            returnItems.push(val2[i]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  for (const st of returnItems) {
    if (val3 == "2") {
      st.sitesStartDateAligned = true;

    }

    if (val3 == "1") {
      st.noOfSites = 1;
      st.pricingMethodId = 2;

    }

    if (this._contract.iterationId == '2' || this._contract.iterationId == '3') {
      st.pricingMethodId = 1;
    }
  }

  this.set('_contract.serviceTypeDetails', returnItems);
  return returnItems;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about filtering an array, in a dom-repeat, based on `serviceTypeItems`?

Comment: Based on `template is="dom-repeat"`, am I right to assume that you're using Polymer 1? Just a warning, but Polymer 1 and 2 will loose support in Chrome soon. Here is how you use dom-repeat in Polymer 3: https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/api/elements/dom-repeat

Comment: @RickardElimää yes, this is Polymer 2.0.

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you posted the code for the dropdown as well. Probably need the relevant properties too. I don't understand what variable that the dropdown changes.

Comment: so two things need to happen for the dom-repeat to display a section called service type detail in the UI. First, the dropdown is to choose the business type (commercial, residential) and the second dropdown is to choose servicetype (gas, electricity, so on) once we make these selections the service type detail section appears in the UI with a bunch of fields, as described, depending on which business type we chose, one or two fields within this section should be prepopulated with set values. 

You would need the code for the custom element for singleselect? or the HTML?

Comment: in addition, everything works fine on the first load, as long as we don't change the business type to the other option (from Comm to Resi or visa versa), the fields in the service type detail section that are supposed to be prepopulated with set value(s) in relevance with te selected business type, won't update.

Comment: The main reason of dom-repeat to not update is that it can't detect a change in the array, but you're returning a totally new array, so that shouldn't be the issue. Not really fond of setting a value (_contract.serviceTypeDetails) while returning another value.

Comment: I need both the HTML for both dropdowns, the HTML code within the dom-repeat and the `properties` that are changed by the dropdowns, the `contract` property, `serviceTypeItems` and anything that may manipulate them all these properties. Please add them to your post.

Comment: Please edit your post, instead of adding the code in the comments.

Comment: Added updated code in the post, really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238667/discussion-between-rickard-elimaa-and-fighithebird).